# Another way to write a complex tsvector query on hstore columns

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm generating rather complex fulltext searches on hstore columns such as:

```
SELECT "users".* 
  FROM "users"  
  WHERE (
    TO_TSVECTOR('german', description -> 'de') @@ PLAINTO_TSQUERY('german', 'foobar') OR 
    TO_TSVECTOR('french', description -> 'fr') @@ PLAINTO_TSQUERY('french', 'foobar') OR 
    TO_TSVECTOR('english', description -> 'en') @@ PLAINTO_TSQUERY('english', 'foobar')
  )
```

Due to limitations on the application layer, I can't put together the above SQL. All I can do is to build a query which would look as follows:

```
WHERE [whatever] [predicate] 'foobar'
```

Say with the `=` predicate:

```
WHERE [whatever] = 'foobar'
```

Now, I'm pretty sure it's not possible to rewrite the complex query above in a manner I can handle on the application layer. But I'd love to be proven wrong here.

Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE
    (TO_TSVECTOR('german', description -> 'de') @@
        PLAINTO_TSQUERY('german', 'foobar')
    )::int +
    (TO_TSVECTOR('french', description -> 'fr') @@
        PLAINTO_TSQUERY('french', 'foobar')
    )::int +
    (TO_TSVECTOR('english', description -> 'en') @@
        PLAINTO_TSQUERY('english', 'foobar')
    )::int
    > '0'
```

A cast of a boolean to integer is 0 or 1. When comparing an integer to a text the text will be cast to integer.

Comment: Nice approach, I'll try this.

Comment: I can almost get it to work with your answer, but the application layer still gets in my way. But it's a very nice approach indeed, so I'll accept the answer nevertheless.